# Form elements not floating?

Tags: html, css, forms, layout

Simple, silly question. Can't seem to wrap my head around it (one of them stupid moments), so figured I might as well give someone some easy karma here.
HTML:

```
<form action="http://localhost/wall/wall_controller/send" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
<input type="text" name="p_name" value="Your name" class="name" maxlength="50" size="25"  />
<textarea name="p_text" cols="20" rows="5" class="message" maxlength="500" >Type your message here</textarea>
<input type="submit" name="send" value="Submit Post!"  />
</form>
```

CSS:

```
.name, .message {
    float: left;
}
```

Why aren't the specified elements floating to the left, as they should be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only float `block` elements. Add a `display: block` rule to `.name, .message`.

Comment: If `float` is not explicitly needed, also consider `display: inline-block`, which can solve many problems `float` is traditionally used to fix. IE7 and lower do not support it, however.